# Converting a number to a Decimal

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I'm trying to convert a number to a decimal(4,1) but it keeps failing in automation studio and I can't figure out what I've done wrong

Code:

```
SELECT 
Total_Staging,
TOTAL_Pre_Sent,
Total_Deployed,
Total_Opens,
Total_Opens_Unique,
Total_Clicks,
jobID,
EmailName,
Total_Bounced,
delivered,
Convert(decimal(4,1), Delivered) as delivered_updated,
Convert(decimal(4,1), Total_Deployed) as Total_Deployed_updated,
Convert(decimal(4,1), Total_Bounced) as Total_Bounced_updated
FROM PH_Daily_Checks
```

In the DE the fields(`delivered_updated,Total_Deployed_updated`,`Total_Bounced_updated`) are all decimal 4,1

I'm also using the above code as a staging table for this final table

```
select 
  Total_Staging,
  TOTAL_Pre_Sent,
  Total_Deployed,
  Total_Opens,
  Total_Opens_Unique,
  Total_Clicks,
  Total_Clicks_Unique,
  jobID,
  EmailName,
  Total_Bounced,
  (delivered_updated2/Total_Deployed_updated2)*100.0 as Delivery_rate_PC
  FROM PH_Daily_Checks_LIVE
Where Dateadd(dd,datediff(dd,0, EVENTDATE),0) = Dateadd(dd, Datediff(dd, 0, GETutcdate()),0)
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What error is it throwing?

Comment: it's just the standard automation error. that's why I can't figure out how to debug the issue.

Comment: Think i fixed it now

Comment: Please share your answer